# Is it possible to modify the data before exporting to excel from ag-grid react table?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a table created using ag-grid enterprise. One of the column has Array of multiple values. I want to duplicate the rows in case of multiple values. Is it possible to manipulate the data before exporting?
I am using default exportDataAsExcel.

I have tried to manipulate the data, but I not sure how can I provide that data to exportDataAsExcel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.